# WildFly Full 18.0.1.Final - how to disable smallrye metrics?

Tags: wildfly

Im trying to completely disable metrics exposed on http://localhost:port/metrics, like:

```
# HELP base_cpu_processCpuLoad Displays the "recent cpu usage" for the Java     
Virtual Machine process.

# TYPE base_cpu_processCpuLoad gauge
base_cpu_processCpuLoad 0.44242270160615144
```

After doing research I've found this line in ../configuration/standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:microprofile-metrics-smallrye:2.0" security-enabled="false" exposed-subsystems="none" prefix="${wildfly.metrics.prefix:wildfly}"/>
```

Setting exposed-subsystems to "none" or leaving it blank should disable the metrics, but it's still exposed, just less data. I need to remove it completely. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to remove the subsystem. This could be done with a management API or endpoint. The simplest would probably be with CLI. The CLI command would look like the following:

```
/subsystem=microprofile-metrics-smallrye:remove
```

You could do this with offline CLI too. Just start `jboss-cli`, `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh`, then start the embedded server.

```
embed-server
/subsystem=microprofile-metrics-smallrye:remove
stop-embedded-server
exit
```

This could also be done with the [`wildfly-maven-plugin`](https://docs.wildfly.org/wildfly-maven-plugin/releases/4.2/execute-commands-mojo.html) if you'd like to do this as part of a build.